# Best way to implement REST API testing with Nightwatch.js

Tags: rest, testing, cucumber, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

I'm using `Nightwatch-Cucumber` that based on `Nightwatch.js`. And I want to integrate REST API tests in my Nightwatch framework. Currently I only have End2End tests based on Selenium, but in future I want to have both test types in one framework to make it also possible to use the End2End tests and the REST API tests in harmony within one Cucumber test. So, I want to combine both tests.

What is the best and smartest way to implement such REST API tests in my test framework based on `Nightwatch-Cucumber`? I've tried some stuff with `frisby.js`, but this framework uses `Jasmine` and `Jest` and it's not a good idea to use it in combination with `Nightwatch` and `Cucumber`.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use request-promise.
In nearest future, new version of nightwatch-cucumber will work with Jasmine and Jest too.

Comment: From where do you know that Jasmine and Jest will be compatible with Nightwatch-Cucumber in future? Is it already documented somewhere?

Comment: Author promised realize them in future